# Calling a stored procedure via EF6 where the Stored Procedure calls another procedure for the result

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0, stored-procedures, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to introduce Entity Framework 6 to a legacy system that depends entirely on stored procedures.

I've got a stored procedure that builds a query which is then passed it to a second query that handles all of the paging requirements. The problem is that when I add the stored procedure to the model, the framework is detecting the return type as being 2 columns (`varchar(4000)` & `varchar(100)`) instead of the actual dataset that is returned when the query is executed.

When I try to run the code, firstly the Just-In-Time debugger crashes with some unhandled win32 exception in w3wp.exe.

Then when I cancel debugging I see the error message

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'TFS_DevModel.spi_QualSearch_Result'. A member of the type, 'provider_code', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

The stored procedure is as follows:

```
declare @SQL varchar(5000),  
@SearchCriteria varchar(1000)

-- build the sorting expression

-- various checks to append criteria based on input parameters

SELECT @SQL = 'select column1, column2, etc from tables ' + 
  @SearchCriteria

execute PagingProc @SQL, @sort_expression, [paging parameters]
```

I have tried to define a complex type to suit the data actually returned by the paging procedure, but I get the same error.

Does anyone know if what I'm trying to do is possible? Or should I look into refactoring the stored procedures?

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching w3wp.exe to the IIS process (Tools > Attach to Process > Scroll down to w3wp.exe, select the correct IIS app pool and click attach). This seems to work for us.

Comment: I'm not sure if this would help since I'm getting an exception in the w3wp process. And I can't see how this would help with the generation of the Entity Model as a result of having a Stored Procedure returning the result of a second SP. Anyway, we've gone down another path, thanks for answering though.